# What is the best error monitoring tool for Ruby on Rails applications?

Tags: monitoring, ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for something to track the errors being raised across our multiple rails applications on our multiple servers.

Ideally: the application failings sends an email to something@something.com and the email is processed in another application. This application will then show us some stats and give us some kinds of auditing tools.

A service like [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home) might do the trick, but I'm trying to see what's available these days. Ideally free or cheap, of course...

Answer (score 1):

You have the choice between [Exceptional](http://www.getexceptional.com/) and Hoptoad. 
Exceptional seems to be the more complete, with a bunch of integration with external services (Lighthouse, sms notification...). The interface is very nice and you can try for free for 40 days.

Hoptoad gathers server and client side (javascript) exceptions. It offers a free plan, limited to 1 user and 1 project. It also integrates with Lighthouse but I didn't tested yet. Seems more simple than Exceptional but does the basics.

Hope it helps